# Headphones noise, turning on and off

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have a Dell XPS13 9333 running Ubuntu 12.04.
Speakers are working ok, while there are issues using headphones. 
Headphone are muted when there is no audio playing (that's ok), than when the audio starts playing (for example, a skype message arrives...but that is true for all kind of audio) I can hear a loud wave sound like in non tuned radios, which goes off a little bit later the audio stops playing.

Typing in terminal

```
sudo aplay -l
```

I get

```
card 0: MID [HDA Intel MID], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC668 Analog [ALC668 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

They say that this is fixed in kernel 3.16 and can be installed like this in Ubuntu 14.04 at least:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
```

This seems to be another issue with the **power management of the soundchip**, the guide on [xps13-9333.appspot.com](http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/#background_noise) suggests to disable power management for Intel HDA on older kernels and to run a certain python script:

> ```
> mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
> wget -O /usr/local/bin/white_noise_fix.py http://xps13-9333.appspot.com/root/usr/local/bin/white_noise_fix.py
> chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/white_noise_fix.py
> ```
>
> After that, disable the power saving mode of the audio card to prevent pop noises, electrical noises and, more importantly, the white noise, which otherwise will come back:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /etc/pm/config.d
> echo INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false > /etc/pm/config.d/snd_hda_intel
> ```

Comment: Looks like the package is only available in trusty/14.04, not precise/12.04 http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&searchon=names&keywords=linux-generic-lts-utopic. I wasn't sure if HWE kernels are released for older LTS releases, but it doesn't look that way currently. So an upgrade to from 12.04 to 14.04 must be done first.